# How to save and restore macOS Launchpad configuration?

Tags: macos, applet, desktop, apple-m2

Often times when I update macOS it screws up the placement of majority of my apps within Launchpad. I'd like to be able to backup it's state so that when I do major updates, I can restore the app placement to what it was beforehand. Usually all the apps are pulled out of my sorted folders and screens and just scattered all over the place.

Thanks.